# Training Loss suddenly increases while validation loss continues decreasing in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I have trained the dense net model on the FER+ dataset; then I tried fine tuning the model on the SEWA database (Here in this case I have regression). So I removed the last dense layer from the original model and replaced it with a new dense layer of 2 outputs instead of 8.

Anyways, while fine tuning the model I used AdamOptimizer, and suddenly after around 50 epochs, the training loss start increasing, while the validation loss continued decreasing, until epoch 80 approximately, and then raised again. Here are the figures that I got:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I wonder how I got this sudden increase in the training loss...Please note that the reported loss is the MSE. Also, in total, the model was trained for 6 hours and 11 mins.

The optimizer I used is AdamOptimizer with learning rate of 0.0005

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: You'll note that after the increase, the training loss proceeds to decrease again. It's possible you were in a local minimum with respect to your training data that did not generalize well. How big are your batches? What happens if you train for 100 epochs? Does the training loss recover?

Comment: @PMende, Alright, will update you after the test!! Thank you for your response. It make sense. As for the batch size, I set it to 64

Comment: The above figures are the updated ones.

Comment: Unrelated but just to check as it might help you. Are you using `tf.data` API already? That'd speed up your training time.

Comment: @AbienFredAgarap, Yes, I am using `tf.data` api... Please let me know what information I should share as well to help find a solution for my problem... I would like to know maybe some hints to know where to debug.. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please take a look at the explanation in this [issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324896/training-loss-increases-with-time) as to why the training loss increases. This might help you in figuring out the solution. Try out the possible solutions and train your model based on that and let me know if the problem still persists. Thanks!